# Change font size in textboxes

Tags: excel, vba

I have pasted textboxes over charts.

I'm trying to change the font size within that textbox for all charts.

This is a picture of what I mean
[image]

```
Sub shapeFont()
Dim shp As Shape

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    With shp.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
    .Size = 30
    End With
Next shp

End Sub
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: ^ And where do you expect it to do that?

Comment: Sorry i should have clarified. I have a series of Charts each with a textbox. I wish to change all the shapes (i.e. textbox) font size to a certain value - here, size 30.

Comment: What do you mean with "charts with a textbox"? Did you drag a textbox inside your charts or something? Some visual representation of what you are dealing with could be helpfull too.

Comment: Yeah. So I have a chart and I've drawn a textbox over it. The textbox has text inside. This format is repeated for 'n' times. I want to change the font size for each textbox which is placed on the charts. I'll upload a pic to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These textboxes seems to be embedded into `ChartObjects`. So you have to loop your `ChartObjects` instead. Then loop over its `Shapes` collection and only when you encounter a proper `TextBox` you should change it's font. Embedded textboxes can be inserted into a chart by selecting a chart and inserting a shape. From then, these shapes move with the chart.

For example:

```
Sub FindTextBoxes1()

    Dim c As ChartObject
    Dim s As Shape

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        For Each s In c.Chart.Shapes
            If s.Type = msoTextBox Then
                s.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 30
            End If
        Next s
    Next c

End Sub
```

Specify a `Workbook` and `Worksheet` variable for pinpointing better where you want this macro to operate (instead of an ugly `ActiveSheet`)

Inspiration from [here](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T013377_Changing_Text_in_Text_Boxes_on_a_Chart.html)

---

Whereas embedded textboxes are great to distinguish shapes you **do** want to change from the ones you **don't** want to change, you also don't need to actually select your textboxes first to be able to change your `Font.Size` in case you want to iterate over all non-embedded textboxes. Simply refer to the `Characters` within the `TextRange`. For example:

```
Sub FindTextBoxes2()

    Dim s As Shape

    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If s.Type = msoTextBox Then
             s.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Size = 30
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant. This seems like the answer. However it runs and nothing changes (and no errors come up)...not sure why?

Comment: I left it as ActiveSheet. I've only got one sheet on that workbook (it's a test case) so I assumed it would be OK. Not sure why it's not working on my end.

Comment: Sorry how do I do that? Is it possible to share workbooks over stackoverflow or do I third party host?

Comment: Okay thank you. [Here is the link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c735490ef482224ff89203bfaf7fe2f820200311105522/13ff2a4ac317d02fd251376ec070da5e20200311105537/0aae0c). Although @Anna 's code worked above, I'd prefer not to use select if possible.

Comment: Your `Textboxes` are **not** embedded. You just pasted them over the charts. If you select a chart, you can actually insert a shape onto the chartarea. From then, the textbox would move around with the chart. Now they are just seperate textboxes. @apang

Comment: Ahhhh... I did not know the difference. I tried it and it now worked. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @apang, glad it helped. I updated my answer in case you may need to iterate over all non-embedded shapes that are textboxes and change their font size. For sanity sake, please remove redundant comments =)

Answer (score 2):

VBA is a strange language if you actually select it it is able to do it..

```
Sub shapeFont()
Dim shp As Shape

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    shp.Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
    .Size = 30
    End With
Next shp
```

End Sub

If chart object is present and you have separate textboxes this works:

```
Sub shapeFont()
Dim shp As Shape

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    shp.Select
    Debug.Print (shp.Type)
    If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
        With Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
       .Size = 50
    End With
   End If
Next shp
End Sub
```

If you want to update the boxes on the chart the code provided by [https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv](http://jvdv) will work

Comment: you can do application.screenupdating = False so It wouldn't be too heavy...

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried this and it says 'Run-time error '438': Object'd doesnt support this property or method'. Im assuming it works for you/you tried it already? Not sure why it doesn't work for mine if so..

Comment: Yes it works on my end - did you copy paste? All I changed in your code is that I select the object, and do with selection. (your code also threw me that error)

Comment: yeah I copy and pasted... that's a bit odd. Perhaps something to do with the version of excel?

Comment: Actually probably because your code is picking up the chart itself - somehow you need to make sure when you loop through the shapes, you don't catch the chart as well let me try

Comment: You're correct. I just ran the code without the chart and it worked. Perhaps it needs to do a For loop for the chart as well? I'll try as well.

Comment: it depends, do you want to update the textboxes on the chart as well, or you put separate textboxes on your charts...

Comment: Just change the font size within the textbox (on the chart) - nothing else. The textbox is already existing.

Comment: do you want to change actually the titles? or the labels and everything as well?

Comment: No - just the external textbox that I've added. My Chart won't have a title. I tried your second block of code you posted above and it worked out